# How to decrease Qt Creator upper left menu options text size?

Tags: qt, ide, qt-creator, text-size

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the images I provided, the upper left menu options text is huge. I don't know why this is, I think I updated Qt and then suddenly it looked like this the next time I ran it. I have tried to search for solutions for how to get regular size back but I find pretty much only things related to code font size. Does anyone know how I can get back the original, much smaller and easy-on-the eyes text size?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in QtCreator 9.0.0. It will be fixed in version 9.0.1. which will hopefully come out soon. If you do not want to wait, you can download and install some snapshot of QtCreator 9.0.1. here https://download.qt.io/snapshots/qtcreator/9.0/9.0.1/ See also https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-28499 for some other workarounds.

Comment: Thank you dude! I figured it would be something like that. I'll see what I will do.